# My Code To Create Two Outer And One Inner JSON List Using Linq To Sql

Tags: javascript, json, vb.net

I have an asp.net WebApi project, I wrote a linq to sql code to return two outer and one inner nested json. However, what I have been able to write is three nested json and when second array don't have data, it blocks the last array even if the last array has data.

I have used DefaultIfEmpty() but to no avail. I have tried creating different queries and merge them but to not avail

Here's my code:

```
Public Function PostAction(<FromBody()> data As Data)
    Dim q = (From x In ctx.CommentsViews
             Where x.PostID = getPostID
             Order By x.CommentDate Descending
             Select New With {x.PostID, x.CommentID, x.Username, x.CommentDate, x.Comment, x.LikesCount, x.RepliesCount, .replies = From y In ctx.ReplysViews.DefaultIfEmpty() Where y.CommentID = x.CommentID Order By y.ReplyDate Descending Select New With {y.ReplyID, y.CommentID, y.Username, y.Fullname, y.Picture, y.Reply, y.LikesCount, y.ReplyDate, .likes = From l In ctx.LikesTbls Where l.PostID = x.CommentID And l.Username = getUser Select New With {l.Username}}}).ToList().Take(3)

    Return q
End Function
```

Below is my json result using Postman

```
[
{
    "PostID": "108",
    "CommentID": 81,
    "Fullname": "David Razak",
    "Username": "550",
    "Picture": "https://localhost:44363/images/C5810018-733D-461E-82A7-487048494049.jpeg",
    "CommentDate": "2019-08-27T21:55:52.91",
    "Comment": "She must be up to something",
    "LikesCount": 2,
    "RepliesCount": 0,
    "replies": []
},
{
    "PostID": "108",
    "CommentID": 80,
    "Fullname": "David Razak",
    "Username": "550",
    "Picture": "https://localhost:44363/images/C5810018-733D-461E-82A7-487048494049.jpeg",
    "CommentDate": "2019-08-27T21:53:59.753",
    "Comment": "Why is she closing her eyes?",
    "LikesCount": 0,
    "RepliesCount": 1,
    "replies": [
        {
            "ReplyID": 1066,
            "CommentID": 80,
            "Username": "550",
            "Fullname": "David Razak",
            "Picture": "https://localhost:44363/images/C5810018-733D-461E-82A7-487048494049.jpeg",
            "Reply": null,
            "LikesCount": 0,
            "ReplyDate": "2019-08-28T12:09:46.243",
            "likes": []
        }
    ]
}
```

]

In the first response, the "likes":[] is not showing because replies has no data. On the second response, the "likes":[] is showing because replies has data

Comment: Why is this tagged as C#. This is VB.

Comment: Sorry about that. It was a mistake.

Comment: If it were working the way you want it to, what would the JSON result look like?